# Geoserver feature extraction "Failed to retrieve value for input features"

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to run the process gs:BufferFeatureCollection in geoserver Demo builder but i am getting the error "gs:BufferFeatureCollectionBufferBuffers features by a distance value supplied either as a parameter or by a feature attribute. Calculates buffers based on Cartesian distances.Failed to retrieve value for input features Unsupported class file major version 57"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using Java 13 (this is what "Unsupported class file major version 57" means anyway).

GeoServer is **only** tested and supported on Java 8 and Java 11. I'm surprised that any of GeoServer is working in this case. Alternatively, you have managed to mix versions of GeoServer and the WPS plugin - you must make sure the major and minor versions match for any GeoServer extension.